# Can you name this GM screen?

Tags: tools, product-identification

I just finished reading this [article about old school D&D](https://medium.com/kickstarter/total-party-kill-3898fb82b5fb), and totally fell in love with the GM screen with the "Conflict Rules" and the map in [this photo](https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/max/2000/1*NIRm8xs9_OreoVrT6iSmzQ.jpeg).

I own a couple of the old screens, but have never seen this particular one before. If anyone knows which module it came bundled with, or the name of the product if it's a stand alone product, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## The Torchbearer GM screen

I'm pretty sure that is the [Torchbearer screen](http://www.torchbearerrpg.com/?p=127), as seen in this image.[image]

Torchbearer is a game based on the Burning Wheel system, written to evoke the real sense of danger and especially scarcity in dungeon-delving.